# Edit app.entitlements file during build phase

Tags: ios, xcode, deep-linking, entitlements, plistbuddy

I have several target in my Xcode project each of them having an associated domain but a different one.

[image: Screenshot a the entitlements file]

I'd like to have the same entitlements file for all my target and having a script with PListBuddy to change the value the domain.

I already have a script that works that I launch during the Build Phases that edit the file correctly :

```
case $TARGET_NAME in
  "EN6") fireBaseUrl="FOO.app.goo.gl";;
  "ES5") fireBaseUrl="BAR.app.goo.gl";;
  "SVT-C4") fireBaseUrl="FOOFOO.app.goo.gl";;
  "PC5") fireBaseUrl="BARBAR.app.goo.gl";;
  *) fireBaseUrl="FOOBAR.app.goo.gl";;
esac

# Universal links used by Firebase
associatedDomainKey="com.apple.developer.associated-domains"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "delete ${associatedDomainKey}" app.entitlements
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :${associatedDomainKey} array" -c "add :${associatedDomainKey}:0 string applinks:${fireBaseUrl}" app.entitlements
```

The problem is that I have a "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements." error when installing the app on a device.

I guess it's because after being edited the entitlements file doesn't corresponds to the entitlements included in the provisioning profile anymore.

Do you know if there is a way to do what I want ? Using fastlane, shell script or anything... (I have 40 targets so I'd really like to get only one entitlements file for all of them)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Kremk No. I had to get a different app.entitlements for each of  my target :-(

Answer (score 3):

Xcode creates an .xcent with your entitlements before signing your app. You can add a Run Script phase as a last step to modify it using PlistBuddy, like this:

```
echo "Updating ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}.xcent"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment string Production" "${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}.xcent" || exit 1
```